# Unable to use backend pagination using Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am having hard time implementing server side pagination using Kendo UI Grid. I have a POST route `/worklist` that does return results when I supply params to it but I am unable to use it using the Kendo UI grid, I have searched a lot online but I cant find anything useful. Here is the result that is returned by the URL when I use Postman to supply params to it.

```
{"header":{"cursor":{"pageable":{"sort":null,"offset":0,"pageSize":5,"pageNumber":0},"page":0,"size":5,"numberOfElements":5,"totalElements":26315,"totalPages":5263},"filter":{"dobFrom":null,"dobTo":null,"inFacility":null,"inICURoom":null,"isICUBaby":null,"hasDocumentWaitingApproval":null,"hasNotification":null,"statusInfoCompleted":false,"statusToBeScreened":false,"statusConsentRequired":false,"statusSecondScreeningDateRequired":false,"statusSecondScreeningDateGiven":false,"statusAppointmentDateRequired":false,"statusAppointmentDateGiven":false,"statusReferredToENT":false,"statusFirstHourOfRehabGiven":false,"statusHaRecommended":false,"riskFactorCode":null,"facilityFollowingPatient":true,"readyToBeScreened":false,"restrictToMyPatientList":false}},"rows":[{"patientId":43101,"patientName":"LAUZON, FLORENCE","sex":"F","statusIcon":"KARAN_ICON","birthDate":"2014-07-22","decesedDate":null,"ramq":"LAUF14572215","mrn":"3009796","mrnFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","followUpFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","location":null,"age":"6 ans 4 mois","motherMaidenName":null,"phoneNumber":"(514)260-8227","address":"1425 RUE UNION","city":"SAINTE-CATHERINE","postalCode":"J5C 1G8","status":"Réussite - fin du PQDSN","statusDate":"2014-08-12"},{"patientId":43102,"patientName":"BETOURNAY, KEITH","sex":"M","statusIcon":"KARAN_ICON","birthDate":"2014-08-18","decesedDate":null,"ramq":"BETK14081812","mrn":"3010677","mrnFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","followUpFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","location":null,"age":"6 ans 3 mois","motherMaidenName":null,"phoneNumber":"(514)451-7657","address":"1735 RANG DUMAS","city":"ORMSTOWN","postalCode":"J0S 1K0","status":"Réussite - fin du PQDSN","statusDate":"2014-08-24"},{"patientId":43103,"patientName":"BETOURNAY, MARLY","sex":"F","statusIcon":"KARAN_ICON","birthDate":"2014-08-18","decesedDate":null,"ramq":"BETM14581814","mrn":"3010678","mrnFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","followUpFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","location":null,"age":"6 ans 3 mois","motherMaidenName":null,"phoneNumber":"(514)451-7657","address":"1735 RANG DUMAS","city":"ORMSTOWN","postalCode":"J0S 1K0","status":"Réussite – surveillance en audiologie recommandée","statusDate":"2014-09-04"},{"patientId":43104,"patientName":"CLIMACO-DOS SANTOS, MATHEO","sex":"M","statusIcon":"KARAN_ICON","birthDate":"2014-07-21","decesedDate":"2015-03-24","ramq":"CLIM14072117","mrn":"3011417","mrnFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","followUpFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","location":null,"age":"6 ans 4 mois","motherMaidenName":null,"phoneNumber":"(438)403-2806","address":"1448, RUE TARDIVEL","city":"LAVAL","postalCode":"H7K 0C2","status":"Décédé","statusDate":"2015-03-24"},{"patientId":43105,"patientName":"CHAGNON, BB DE SINDY","sex":"F","statusIcon":"KARAN_ICON","birthDate":"2014-08-04","decesedDate":null,"ramq":null,"mrn":"3011180","mrnFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","followUpFacilityCode":"CHUSJ","location":null,"age":"6 ans 4 mois","motherMaidenName":null,"phoneNumber":"(450)793-2578","address":"72 DION","city":"SAINT-LIBOIRE","postalCode":"J0H 1R0","status":"Réussite – surveillance en audiologie recommandée","statusDate":"2014-09-04"}]}
```

This is the result when explicitly mention that I need the first five results , how can I display this through kendo UI Grid, I am using the `pageSize` and the `total` records variable but no luck.
Here is my jQuery Kendo UI code

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       contentType: "application/json",
                       url: "worklist",
                       dataType: 'json',
                       cache: false
                   })
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            timeout: 600000,
            pageSize: 10,
        },
        schema: {
            total: '26315',
            model: {
                fields: {
                    patientName: { type: 'string'},
                    birthDate: { type: 'string'},
                    phoneNumber: { type: 'string'},
                    ramq: { type: 'string'},
                    address: { type: 'string'},
                    mrn: { type: 'string'}
                }
            }
        },
        height: 550,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "patientName",
                title: 'Patient name'
            },
            {
                field: "birthDate",
                title: 'BirthDate'
            },
            {
                field:"ramq",
                title:"RAMQ"
            },
            {
                field:"address",
                title: "Address"
            },
            {
                field:"mrn",
                title: "MRN"
            }]
    });

});
```

using this, in my network tab I keep getting a 404 Not found, apparently the library is not supplying any params to the request, however I do see the empty Kendo UI grid being displayed on the page.Thanks for the help

Comment: Not sure where exactly is your problem but you do know that `kendoGrid` appends `page`, `pageSize`, `skip` and `take` as query parameters when you do server paging, don't you? Does your `/worklist` endpoint take this into account?

Comment: @jpllosa Yes my endpoint supports pagination and is sortable as well you can see in the response snippet I have pageSize and pageNumber properties, I am not sure about skip and take but regardless I should not be getting a 404, is there something I am missing in the Ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further consultation with my teammates, I found a solution. Seems you have to create a `dataSource` and in the params you need to just send the following `{page: dataSource._page - 1, size: dataSource._pageSize}`

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json",
               url: "worklist",
               dataType: 'json',
               cache: false,
               data:JSON.stringify({page: dataSource._page - 1, size: dataSource._pageSize})
           }).done(function (result) {
               options.success(result);
            }).fail(function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + " " + httpRequest);
            })
        }
    }, 
    schema: {
        data: function (result) {
            return result.rows;
        },
        total: function (result) {
            return result.header.cursor.totalElements;
        },
        model: {
            fields: {
                patientName: { type: 'string'},
                birthDate: { type: 'string'},
                phoneNumber: { type: 'string'},
                ramq: { type: 'string'},
                address: { type: 'string'},
                mrn: { type: 'string'}
            }
        },
    },
    
    pageSize: 15,
    serverPaging: true,
    timeout: 600000,
    
});
// Kendo Grid
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        height: 550,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "patientName",
                title: 'Patient name'
            },
            {
                field: "birthDate",
                title: 'BirthDate'
            },
            {
                field:"ramq",
                title:"RAMQ"
            },
            {
                field:"address",
                title: "Address"
            },
            {
                field:"mrn",
                title: "MRN"
            }
        ]
    });

});
```